# New line in textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a textbox1 that lets the user input a text, a button that adds the text to textbox2.
this is my code but it doesnt create a new line when I add another text.

```
 string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
 txt_details.Text = date + "  " + txt_summary.Text.ToString() +    Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine ;
```

Comment: Did you remember to set the Multiline property of the TextBox to true?

Comment: `txt_summary.Text.ToString()` sigh. `textBox.Text` is a string. No need to `toString()` it.

Comment: yes i did set the multiline property to true.

Comment: You aren't appending any text after the newlines - did you mean to?

Answer (score 3):

1. Looks like you should be appending (use `+=`); instead you are overwriting.

   ```
   string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
   txt_details.Text += date + "  " + txt_summary.Text.ToString() +    Environment.NewLine +  Environment.NewLine
   ```
2. Make sure `Multiline` is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the `+=` operator.

```
txt_details.Text += "\n" + date + "  " + txt_summary.Text.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that [`TextBox.Multiline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff.aspx) property is set to true

```
txt_details.Multiline = true;
```